# Describe a plane in a matrix metric space

Tags: matrices, geometry, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a matrix metric space where the distance between two matrices is given by the Frobenius metric.
Distance between matrices $A$ and $B$:
$$ \sqrt{Tr \left((A-B)^\dagger(A-B)\right)} $$

How do I describe a hyperplane in this metric space? Ideally I would like to understand the geometry of such a space to be able to play around with it. For example be able to draw parallel planes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ with the inner product 
$$ 
 \langle A,B\rangle_F = \mathrm{Tr}(A^T B)
$$
can be regarded as the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ with the usual inner product $\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{w}=\mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{w}$. You can just use the identification (isomorphism)
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
   a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
   \vdots &        &        & \vdots \\
   a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn}
  \end{bmatrix}
  \mapsto
 (a_{11}, a_{12}, \ldots,a_{21}, a_{22}, \ldots, a_{mn}).
$$
In particular, a hyperplane can be described as
$$
        Tr(A^T X) =b
$$
where $A$ is a constant matrix, $b$ a real constant and $X$ a matrix whose components are variables. The matrix $A$ can be interpreted as a vector normal to the hyperplane. By changing the constant $b$, you will get a plane parallel to the original plane.

Comment: The inner product in the vector case uses all n^2 parameters of the vector, but in the matrix case, if you diagonalize the matrix (assuming square), the inner product uses only the diagonal n elements of the matrix. How is it an isomorphism?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you want to diagonalise $A$? And the map is an isomorphism because $Tr(A^T B)=(\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n a^2_{ij})^{1/2}$, which is also the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$.

Comment: Yeah, got it, thank you